# Add price to price final in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I override a big part of the front of the products with JS. I would like to be able to update my price from the "Add to cart" button. Currently the price of my product in backoffice is at 1 € and I add in JS amounts in addition. See the attached screenshot:

[image: price]

Except that when I click on "Add to cart" the price is at 1 €.

[image: price2]

I award my price to the price of the product like this:

```
function updatePrice(tabOptions) {
// Update prices options
var format = price_format_page[tabOptions['is_format_page']];
var color = price_color_page[tabOptions['is_color_page']];
var impression = price_impression_page[tabOptions['is_impression_page']];
var paper = price_paper_page[tabOptions['is_paper_page']];
var reliure = price_reliure_page[tabOptions['is_reliure_page']];
var color_reliure = price_color_reliure_page[tabOptions['is_color_reliure_page']];
var finition = price_finition_page[tabOptions['is_finition_page']];

if (tabOptions['is_color_page'] === 'Couleur') {
    var page = price_per_page * tabOptions['page_value'];
} else {
    var page = price_per_page_nb * tabOptions['page_value'];
}

var total_options = format + color + impression + paper + reliure + color_reliure + finition + page + productPriceTaxExcluded;

/*// Get combination prices
 var combID = $('#idCombination').val();
 var combination = combinationsFromController[combID];
 if (typeof combination == 'undefined')
 return;*/

// Set product (not the combination) base price
var basePriceWithoutTax = total_options;
var basePriceWithTax = +productPriceTaxIncluded;
var priceWithGroupReductionWithoutTax = 0;
```

Comment: If you change the price with js, it will not change the price in your store. The price is still the same, the js is changing it only what the customer sees in that field, not the product price. You need to create combinations, or use a module that allows you to do what you want (setting options for products).

Comment: I do not want to change in the store the price of the products is at the order level.

Comment: A combination is a way to set different attributes for a product with different proces or not. You can set a product combination with color red one price, and with color black another price. And these options will show in your product page.

Comment: These are not colors that I would like to display but much more. I have added an upload button that parses the document and calculates the page number based on a price per page. And there are different select button with different options with different prices.

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 0):

The price of a product throughout the PrestaShop is calculated by the getPriceStatic() function defined in Product.php class which calls the getSpecificPrice() function of SpecificPrice.php class

In case you want to change the price of a product on run-time, then it will be better to override the getSpecificPrice() function of SpecificPrice.php class

Comment: Okay but I have to add my price on what variable? Or what should I do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello, Do you have any idea how I could spend my price modify in product.js in my specificPrice controller? Thank you